# Cannot activate direct-to mode on Garmin GNS 530

Tags: microsoft-flight-simulator

In Flight Simulator 2020, when flying the Cessna 172, I click the "direct-to" button on the GNS 530 and enter the airport code. The next step is hitting enter twice to activate, but pressing enter the second time does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this on the steam gauge Cessna 172 that comes with the Deluxe edition?

Comment: In any case, I have noticed that the "direct to" buttons are pretty broken so far on every aircraft type, so it seems likely to me that you're not doing anything wrong, unfortunately

Comment: Seems like sim speed is buggy too ... Increasing to 4x causes AP in the 172 to porpoise like crazy...

Comment: It's like they didn't tune the AP PID loop. Even heading hunts around..

Comment: ETA to waypoint on GNS 530 also displays ETA without a leading zero in seconds ... "1:5" means "1 minute 5 seconds" lol..

Comment: Lots of little bugs. Where's my flight analysis?

Comment: And I can't get back to the main map view on the Garmin! wtf... Can't activate approach either. How did this make it through QA?

Comment: This thing is buggy as all get out.. I'm flying heading 000, GPS shows me going SW...

Comment: And my AP is now flying 30 degrees left of the heading bug ...